# Animated list item expansion with RecyclerView?

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

How can I achieve this neat list item expansion effect with the Android RecyclerView?

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ruWrqab0Jb0#t=6)

So far I was only able to find tutorials on this for the old ListView API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are a few ways to do such an effect, but the way that I'd do it really wouldn't have anything to do with `ListView`, or `RecyclerView`. That more has to do with the actual displaying of the items of data. What we're seeing in the video is a behavior when an item is clicked.

**Here is how I'd do it:**
1. Create a custom `View` that extends `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, or `FrameLayout`.
2. You essentially have 2 states, expanded state, and non-expanded state. Have the view intercept click events, and when it's clicked in non-expanded state, it animate an expand. This should automatically animate the other views in the `RecyclerView` down, and then animate in the new information after the growing animation is complete.

What you are asking is fairly complex, but that is the general gist of how I would do it. I'd get this working as a view by itself before I started adding it to the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Don't forget to mention that items should not have fixed size.

Comment: Wouldn't that affect other views as well, since RecyclerView reuses views? You would scroll down and would see multiple expanded views instead of just the one the user expanded.

Comment: @Doge has a good point. When setting data on each item, you should reset the size as well.

Comment: It works fine, but if you expand the last view item, the recycle view does not scroll up. A custum scroll listener needs to be written there.